# How to combine these two SQL statements to avoid GROUP BY error?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine two SQL statements into one, but am running into GROUP BY errors for full_group_only, which I understand why, but not how to solve.

In the first query, I am simply getting the number of actions per item, and in the second query, I am getting the latest action.

Assume a simple setup as:

```
actions (id, item_id, description)
items (id, name)
```

With the two queries

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS actions_number FROM actions GROUP BY item_id 

SELECT * FROM actions WHERE id in (SELECT max(id) FROM actions GROUP BY item_id)
```

How do I easily combine these two statements into one?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: In this case, it does not make much sense to post the plethora of broken queries I've created, when all I am attempting to do is create one working query, that combines the two above

Comment: Please post sample input data and expected output. I don't see any of the above query throwing full_group_only related error

Comment: can you add an example of what the output should look like?  basically you want to do an inner join on the same table (actions) but you give them different aliases (a1 and a2 for example).  Some of the result will come from a1 and some will come from a2.  good luck!

Comment: I am looking to `SELECT *, COUNT(*) as actions_number FROM actions`, grouped by item_id.

So it would contain the `number of actions per item`, as well as the `data for the latest action.` (It is getting the latest action in the second query with max(id) since the id's are sequential)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.actions_number
FROM
    actions a
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT 
        MAX(id) id, COUNT(*) actions_number
    FROM
        actions
    GROUP BY item_id) b ON a.id = b.id;
```